# How to enable checkboxes in Virtual TreeView columns headers?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I'm using Virtual TreeView V5.0.1 (06 Sep 2012) in Delphi XE2. Setting `CheckBox := True` on a header column property does not enables the checkbox, so here's the question, how do I enable checkboxes on column headers?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this seemingly simple question brought a dozen of Google results that tried to hack the header drawing through `OwnerDraw` and painting checkboxes manually.

Where's the solution I want to share is quite simple, enable following two items in IDE: 
include `hoShowImages` into `VirtualTree.Header.Options` set and `toCheckSupport` into `VirtualTree.TreeOptions.MiscOptions` set.

Then you can enable `Header.Column[0].CheckBox` property and see desired result.

Comment: Also, if you want to use the checkbox, say to select all items in a list, it goes under the header's OnClick.